# nohup problem when given command with arguments

Tags: signal, nohup

Tried:

```
while true; do date; sleep 1; done
```

Got:

```
Thu Aug 27 17:33:24 IDT 2009
Thu Aug 27 17:33:25 IDT 2009
Thu Aug 27 17:33:26 IDT 2009
...
```

But:

```
nohup while true; do date; sleep 1; done
```

Got me:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do'
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you REALLY wanted to do it all on the command line without making a script, do this:

```
nohup bash -c "while true; do date; sleep 1; done"
```

Answer (score 2):

nohup takes a command, "while" is not a command, it is a shell builtin.

Answer (score 1):

while is actually a command that is built into bash, not a separate executable, so nohup can't run it.  If you want to do this, you'll need to put your commands into a file and then use nohup to run that file.